# A more elegant way to write this? (Deck of cards)

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a Blackjack simulator, and I'm generating n decks of cards to play with:

```
int i;
int value = 1;
for (i = 0; i < deck->n_cards; i++) {
    deck->cards[i] = value;
    value++;
    if (value == 14) value = 1;
}
```

(deck->n_cards % 52 == 0)

I tried an approach to write the same with modulo operations, but I can't get it away using more than 1 deck. I think that using that if is really ugly. Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: You want to reset value to 1 if it hits 14?

Comment: I think `i%13 + 1`

Comment: You'll probably get better results if you use 0-12 rather than 1-13 for your card values. A zero-based numbering scheme is going to work better if you use an array to (for example) name the cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Blackjack play, however I understand from your code, the values range is 1 to 13. 
Try this code:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < deck->n_cards; i++) {
    deck->cards[i] = (i % 13) + 1;
}
```

i%13 range is 0 to 12, adding one to this, makes this range 1 to 13

Comment: It should be `i%13`, cause value was compared with 14, and the value was greater then 1 to i. ; )

Comment: Yes, you are right, it shall be i%13, I fixed it at the answer above.

Comment: For completeness, a magic one-liner: `for (int i = 0; i < deck->n_cards; deck->cards[i] = (i++ % 13) + 1);` Don\`t try this at home =)

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to use "magic" numbers in your code.  Define, or Enumerate some values...  You only care about the value of the cards when you're totaling each hand.

```
#define CARDS_IN_DECK 52
#define CARDS_IN_SUIT 13
#define DECKS_IN_BOOT 8
#define SUITS_IN_DECK 4

#define HEARTS 0
#define SPADES 1
#define CLUBS  2
#define DIAMONDS 3
#define CARD_SUIT(c)  suits[((c)/CARDS_IN_SUIT)]
#define CARD_FACE(c)  cards[((c)%CARDS_IN_SUIT)]
#define CARD_VALUE(c) cardValue[((c)%CARDS_IN_SUIT)]

int deck[DECKS_IN_BOOT][CARDS_IN_DECK];
int boot, card;
int needsShuffle = 1;
const char *suits[] = {"Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};
const char *cards[] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
                  "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
const int cardValue[] = {11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10};

void shuffle()
{
    int num_shuffles = 1000;
    int i, j, k, m, n, temp;

    printf("\n\t Shuffling ... \n");
    /* Create the boot */
    for (i=0;i<DECKS_IN_BOOT;i++)
        for (j=0;j<CARDS_IN_DECK;j++)
            deck[i][j] = j;

    for ( ;num_shuffles--; )
    {
        m = rand() % DECKS_IN_BOOT;
        n = rand() % DECKS_IN_BOOT;

        j = rand() % CARDS_IN_DECK;
        k = rand() % CARDS_IN_DECK;

        temp = deck[n][j];
        deck[n][j] = deck[m][k];
        deck[m][k] = temp;
    }
    needsShuffle = boot = card = 0;
}

void testPrintDeck()
{
    int i, j;

    /* Create the boot */
    for (i=0;i<DECKS_IN_BOOT;i++)
        for (j=0;j<CARDS_IN_DECK;j++)
            printf("%d %s %s\n",
                   deck[i][j],
                   CARD_FACE(deck[i][j]),
                   CARD_SUIT(deck[i][j]));
}

main(int c, char *v[])
{
    srand(time(0));
    shuffle();
    testPrintDeck();
}
```

Comment: I don't really care about the suits nor cards, I'm only interested in the actual value. What do you mean by "magic" numbers?

Comment: @Norhther Instead of using 13 use something representative of 13 like `CARDS_IN_SUIT` otherwise 13 might just be your lucky number for all anyone reading the code knows.  Don't you want to display the card along with the suit in your simulation?

Comment: I don't really need to display the card. I get what you meant, so I will use `#define`.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is, given a pointer to 52 int array, fill it in 4 sets of 1-13, a simpler approach would be, IMO:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct deck{
    int n_cards;
    int cards[52];
}deck_t;

 int main(void) {

    deck_t *deck = malloc(sizeof(deck_t));
    deck->n_cards = 52;

    int value = 1, suit_size = 13, num_of_suits = 4;

    /* 1st option*/
    for(int i = 0; i < deck->n_cards / num_of_suits; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < deck->n_cards; j += suit_size){
            deck->cards[i+j] = value;
        }
        value++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < deck->n_cards; i++){
        printf("%d ", deck->cards[i]);
    }

    /* 2nd option*/
    value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < deck->n_cards; i++){
        deck->cards[i] = 1 + value++ % 13;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < deck->n_cards; i++){
        printf("%d ", deck->cards[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```